# English grammar: time and place in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis, sentence

Is it compulsory to always place time at the end of a sentence?

For example:

"I bought a cake in the morning. I ate the cake in the afternoon."

"In the morning, I bought a cake. In the afternoon, I ate the cake."

Is the second sentence grammatically incorrect?

Comment: No, the time does not have to go at the end of the sentence.

Comment: It sounds a little poetical, and is correct too.

Answer (score -1):

Its not a problem to put time in front of sentence, but its more likely to be put at the end of the sentence. Try this: 
 https://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/satzstellung_2.htm

Comment: I think clause is more accurate than sentence. Consider 'I bought a cake this morning but in the afternoon I gave it away'